# Add COUNT(*) from different tables including WHERE statements and GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I have three queries like this:

`select count(*) as customers, created_at::date as date from table1 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL group by created_at::date order by created_at::date ASC`

`select count(*) as customers, created_at::date as date from table2 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL group by created_at::date order by created_at::date ASC`

`select count(*) as customers, created_at::date as date from table3 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL group by created_at::date order by created_at::date ASC`

What I need is to end up with two columns: a date and a sum total of `customers` from the three tables. I tried with a subquery, but wasn't sure how to position the `GROUP BY` without getting errors. I tried something like this:

`select ((select count(*) as customers, created_at::date as date from table1 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL group by created_at::date order by created_at::date ASC)+(select count(*) as customers, created_at::date as date from table2 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL group by created_at::date order by created_at::date ASC)+(select count(*) as customers, created_at::date as date from table3 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL group by created_at::date order by created_at::date ASC)) AS SumCount`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right...got two things I was working on mixed up. Question still remains though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could use `union all` to combine data from your tables and then perform aggregation

```
select t.date, count(*)
from (
    select  created_at::date as date from table1 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL 
    union all
    select  created_at::date as date from table2 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL
    union all
    select created_at::date as date from table3 where subscription_ends_at IS NOT NULL
) t
group by t.date
order by t.date
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.